# How to connect a 1/4 NPT pressure gauge to a schrader valve while being airtight

Tags: pressure, airflow, pumps, valves

I need to attach this pressure gauge - https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07CXM3ZGT/ref=ask_ql_qh_dp_hza - to a schrader valve with a pipe to measure the pressure.

The valve has a 1/4 NPT thread. I made the mistake of buying this pressure gauge before checking how compatible it was with a schrader valve and after lots of searching I'm finding it difficult to figure out how to connect them while being airtight.

Could someone recommend an adapter and/or pipe to help me connect them? I'm new to engineering and don't know the best place to look.
I'm questioning if something like this [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08GJT8B8X/ref=aod_recs_desktop_prsubs_0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08GJT8B8X) would work, however I also require at least a foot long pipe to connect them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So get a pipe with 1/4 NPT on both ends one male one female to go with your choices so far.

Comment: are you talking about a permanent connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schrader valves, such as are used on car tires, have threads that are not compatible with anything. If you want a semi-permanent solution, you will need to buy (or make) a special Schrader-NPT fitting.  They exist but are not so common.

If you are talking about a temporary connection such as would be done with the inflator chuck you linked to, both show as 1/4 NPT so you can screw the gauge into the chuck.  If you need more distance, any (US) hardware store will be happy to sell you the fittings to make the connection.  While you are there, you will want to buy some Teflon tape thread sealant. The NPT (American [National Pipe Taper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_pipe_thread#Types)) threads expect to have something on them to keep the threads from leaking.

An alternative would be to buy something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0002SQYT6).  Your gauge could be screwed into one end and the other end will fit over the valve.  If you need more distance, you will need some kind of adaptor, such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B082V8FJQJ) to join two NPT connections together and [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002JG46GC) to provide as much distance as you need.  Again, you will need some [thread sealant](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01DMNPXKI).

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful and I will look into these things.

Answer (score 0):

There are adapters that have a little button in them to depress the schrader pin. But they don't usually have a swivel. So you need the adapter connected to a valve, then to the pipe. Try an A/C shop if you cant find them at your autoparts store. They are used by refrigeration techs quite a lot.

[McMaster](https://mcmaster.com/adapters/thread-type%7Eschrader/)
[image]